# How to remove element from ChartArea

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mschart

I am creating a chart control

```
chart1.ChartAreas.Add("area");
chart1.series.add("time");

//loop    
//get values of a and b from excel sheet    
chart1.Series["time"].Points.AddXY(a, b);
//endloop
```

I have to plot a graph between A and B.Now when second time the application is started it shows that ChartControl already contain a member called area.

So i want to remove area from chart control and time from series.How to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean to say when you refresh the `ChartArea` and `Series` are being added again.

Please check if they are added within a `if (! IsPostBack)`

else you would need to add something like

```
Chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
Chart1.Series.Clear();
```

before adding the `ChartArea`, `Series`.

if not please add additional details to your question.